# DockPanel in UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I would like to know if there is anyway to reproduce the same behavior than with the `DockPanel` in WPF but in UWP app?

I would like to have some container docked, and the last one filling the userinterface?

Thank you

Comment: Another example of MS - "Who moved my cheese?".  I miss `DockPanel`

Comment: It's included in the UWP Community Toolkit: https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend [RelativePanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel).
It's not exactly like a DockPanel, but you can make it behave like one pretty easily using the `RelativePanel.Align*` attached properties.

Comment: Can you do the "LastChildFill" ?

Comment: there is no "LastChildFill" property, but you can have an element "fill" the space by using RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel or RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel, etc. Like I said, it's not completely the same, but can ultimately achieve the same result. If you have an example of layout you want to create, I will post a sample code to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find DockPanel in [XAML Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/)
It's not documented well, but in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS6a9dVunq4&feature=youtu.be&t=2m02s) you can see DockPanel

Comment: I didn't know this toolkit. I checked the video and there seems to have a lot of unexpected behavior in it. Is this still maintained?

Comment: Some of controls from this toolkit are already embedded in Win10, but some of them are still actual (and some depricated). As you can find this tolkit was updated last time in march.